# Search, match and display all counts perl

Tags: arrays, string, perl, printing, count

I am pretty clue'd up with perl, I am however struggling with something (must be time of year)

I am issuing 2 commands, one will get all items of a specific class and then store all these items in an array.

```
    @array = `get_class_command -class=type`;
```

I then issue another command to get the property of the class

```
    $foreach my $item(@items) {
    $item =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
    system("get_property_command -type=property"); # I can also assign this to a value.
    }
```

So the above will only give me a list of all the properties. for instance:

```
    property_CA
    property_CE
    property_CR
    property_CA
    property_CA
    property_CA
    property_CR
    property_CA
```

So I am able to now either print all the different classes and all the types and all the properties, I am also able to specify that I want only the count for specific items. by defining them.
What I however cannot seem to figure out is how to display all items in a count without having to define what I want. So I want to go through the commands, check each of the properties and display the name once and then print the number of counts. for instance:

```
    property_CA = 5
    property_CE = 1
    property_CR = 2
```

If I define in the script what to match I can do this, but I would need to know each property in order to define it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Use hash to count repeating elements, `$hash{$item}++` http://perlmaven.com/count-words-in-text-using-perl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 foreach my $item ( @items ) {
    my $property = `command to get thingys`
    $count_of{$property}++;
 }


 foreach my $property ( keys %count_of ) {
    print "$property $count_of{$property}\n";
 }
```